# jQuery – jExpand plugin - expand via image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, toggle

I'm looking at :
Expand table rows with jQuery – jExpand plugin.

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/expand-table-rows-with-jquery-jexpand-plugin/

This does what I want but I only want the row toggleable via the arrow icon, not by clicking on the entire row.

I've tried changing `$("#report tr.odd").click(function(){` to pickup the arrow class, but nothing has worked.

Could someone point me in the right direction!

Comment: Can you, please, post a `JSFiddle` containing your try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two changes you need to make

css change :

```
#report tr.odd td { background:#fff url(row_bkg.png) repeat-x scroll center left; }
.arrow { cursor:pointer;}
```

JavaScript change :

```
$(".arrow").click(function(){
  $(this).parents("tr").next("tr").toggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("up");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/566aT/3/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the click to bind to the arrow, then make sure you go back to the TR context. Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/566aT/)

```
$("#report tr.odd .arrow").click(function(){
                $(this).closest('tr').next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).closest('tr').find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
            });
            //$("#report").jExpand();
        });
```